# How do I encode a COSE signed message?

Tags: python, encryption, cbor

I'm experimenting with encryption.
I have successfully decoded a COSE message from a string.
I would now like to encode it back.
I tried to use the [COSE library](https://pypi.org/project/cose/) to do that, but don't know how to compile each field of it. My string is something like:

```
<COSE_Sign1: [{'KID': b'4\x92B\xb1\xc2\xd3r\xfe', 'Algorithm': 'Es256'}, {}, b'\xb4\xb4\x1bd]' ... (227 B), b'bR\x20\xf1\x2e' ... (64 B)]>
```

and for encoding purposes I'm asked to fill in this data:

```
msg = Enc0Message(
    phdr={'ALG': 'A128GCM', 'IV': unhexlify(b'01010101010101010101010101010101')},
    uhdr={'KID': b'meriadoc.brandybuck@buckland.example'},
    payload='a secret message'.encode('utf-8')
)
```

Could somebody help me, please?
Thanks